# Streaming file with extra information WCF 4.5

Tags: wcf, .net-4.5, file-transfer

I'm setting up a webservice which needs to receive files, sometimes the files may be > 10MB so I decided to use the latest stream functionality in WCF 4.5. Unfortunately it looks like I can only use a stream if it is the only parameter in the method, like this -

```
public void SendLargeFile(Stream stream)
```

So how can I get more information passed along with the file, like variables about what the file is and what needs to be done with it? It seems like just sending the file is a bit useless. What I'd like to do is something like this -

```
public void SendLargeFile(Stream stream, string fileName, string customerName)
```

I've seen some people taking about Messages but it seems like a real mess in comparison to all it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider creating a `[DataContract]` for your parameter:

```
public void SendLargeFile(SendLargeFileRequest request)
```

and the request is:

```
[DataContract]
public class SendLargeFileRequest 
{
      [DataMember] 
      public Stream stream;
      [DataMember] 
      public string fileName;

      [...]
}
```

This helps you make changes to your request in future without modifying the signature of your `OperationContract`

Comment: That throws an error - There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:request. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.IO.FileStream' with data contract name 'FileStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'

Comment: Stream is an abstract class. If you are sending a FileStream on the wire you should use the `FileStream` as your `DataMember` instead of `Stream`. This helps the DataContractSerializer to serialize the `FileStream` properly. Or simply use `MemoryStream` if you want to decouple this with using `FileStream` explicitly

Comment: I tried FileStream as a DataMember and it passes through WCF ok but the FileStream is empty on the server side.

Comment: This is one big problem with streams, you need to set the position to 0 before sending it on wire - like `stream.Position = 0;`

Comment: It's still empty, do you have an example. I'm pretty sure I can't use a stream like this after reading MSDN.

Comment: Can you make sure you are not sending empty stream from client side, also could you please post the code where you are using the stream.

Comment: I went with a byte array in the end. Couldn't get the stream to work at all.

Comment: Byte array is best fit for wcf over stream, I did the same when I was doing a wcf service for sharepoint in the past.